# Best way to login to wordpress with Angular

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, authentication

Using Angular, I am trying to post a Wordpress CPT from the front.

It works fine when I'm logged in, using `$http.post` to RestApi,
and with `x-wp-nonce` included via the interceptors:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push([function() {
    return {
        request: function(config) { 
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            config.headers['X-WP-Nonce'] = appInfo.nonce;
            return config
        }
    };
}]);
```

But of course it does not work when I'm logged out.
What would be the easiest way to login without the user to see it ?

I would like any non-wp-user to be able to post a draft CPT from the front, say using a wp user called visitor.

Thank you.